# What was Mongul referring to about red suns?

Tags: dc, young-justice

In *Young Justice* Season 2 Episode 15 "War", Mongul says the following to Superboy:

> Little Kryptonian. So proud of your powers. Did you truly believe yours was the only race to come from a world with a red sun?

What race was he referring to? Mongul's own? Other races Mongul would have fought?

Also, is this implying that the nature of red suns affects the biology of species so that they are super-powered in yellow suns?

I realize Young Justice is a closed continuity, but I'm willing to accept answers that have insight from other DC timelines. For instance, I know that Sodam Yat's people, the Daxamites, have/had a red sun, and get abilities like Superman from yellow suns, being genetic cousins to Kryptonians. However, I don't know enough about Mongul or Sodam's histories to know if they've had encounters outside of Mongul's Sinestro Corp stint. Thus, I don't know if that could be what Mongul is referring to in this episode.

And, of course, quotes from people involved in writing or running the show would be excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Greg Weisman](http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/search.php?qid=19400), Mongul is indeed referring to his own people.

> **Q.** *Mongol's powers are red sun related? But I thought he's that powerful everywhere.*
>
> **GW:** *Mongul is a big, strong, powerful guy. Under a yellow sun, his powers
> (though not exactly the same) rise to the level of Superman's. He
> can't fly, but he's far stronger. Under a red sun, he has no powers,
> but he's still far stronger than a normal human - and far stronger
> than Superman would be under that same red sun. I still wouldn't want
> to meet him in a dark alley.*

Comment: Wow, wasn't expecting that kind of clarity. But where did he actually respond, since that's just a record of it?

Comment: @CreationEdge - If you click into the main page, the site features an "ask greg" page where you can pose questions to the creator; http://www.s8.org/gargoyles/askgreg/

Comment: I always miss web stuff on mobile. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. I *know* I did this on mobile, but the app must've farted out. I've had that issue before.

Comment: Nice one. Where I feel my answers are definitive (word of God), I set a reminder to prod the OP after about twenty days.